# What statistical treatment can I do to a group of data of a single parameter?

Tags: machine-learning

I just started the Statistics course and I need to know how to develop the statistical analysis of a group of data.
These data belong to the same parameter and were taken at 17 sampling stations in triplicate. How should I develop the statistical treatment of these experimental results? How could I start and what to evaluate in them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "belong to the same parameter". Do you mean there is only one variable?

As to what you should do, this is backwards. What do you want to find out?